# How to refresh a materialized view incrementally in PostgreSQL i.e. only for the data that is new or has changed?

Tags: postgresql, insert, materialized-views

How to implement fast refresh materialized view postgresql
How to update only new changes to materialized view from base tables

Comment: [Refresh materalized view incrementally in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86779/38456)

Answer (score 7):

I've been following this new development for a while hoping it would be finalized and added to Postgresl 14: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Incremental_View_Maintenance.

Here is a blog post with some performance numbers: https://yugonagata-pgsql.blogspot.com/2021/04/implementing-incremental-view_61.html

Here is part III with links to github and dockerhub: https://yugonagata-pgsql.blogspot.com/2021/06/implementing-incremental-view.html

Github source code: https://github.com/sraoss/pgsql-ivm

Docker image for testing purposes: https://hub.docker.com/r/yugonagata/postgresql-ivm

**EDIT 2022-03-24**: seems this has been moved to version 16, see [Postgresql Incremental Materialized View Maintenance (IVM) challenges, why delay it again to targetversion 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427975/postgresql-incremental-materialized-view-maintenance-ivm-challenges-why-delay)